# What is this section category in Model Library Setup in Cadence Virtuoso ADE L?

Tags: circuit-design, library, cadence, eda

I usually leave it at default while constructing circuit in Cadence Virtuoso. I didn't really understand what it is or why it is used for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Library, if you are designing many blocks like bandgaps, I/O's, current mirrors, level shifters etc. You can categorize them under different categories which will be helpful for you to select/look at a block in future. It's just for the simplicity.

Comment: In Global Model files section I have NN, SS, SF, FS, FF , etc. in drop down list. What does that mean?

Comment: It's the process corners, Nominal-Nominal, Slow-fast...etc...pmos is slow, nmos is fast (strong-weak) kind of notation, to imply the drive strength of the mosfets depending on process corners.

Comment: Should I change it according to a specific design? or leave it at default.

Comment: You can leave it default if you don't have many designs. It's useful when you have a lot number of designs, which have different functions from one another

Comment: Let's say I want to design a CMOS Inverter, which should I use?

Comment: Regarding the model file selection, by default you're supposed to make sure the design is valid/functional with performance across those process corners

Answer (score 0):

These are the sections in the model file. You have many sections in the model file, which are different from each other. The difference is usually the global variations (=process corners), but it could be as well including the parasitics, or whether or not assert warnings instead of errors will be used. In some PDKs the monteCarlo models are needed to stated directly, with section=mc. There are endless possibilities.

Basically you can select the correct model for your circuit from the model file which is a collection of models even for the same type of device.

You should consult your PDK documentation how to use them. As long as you just want to simulate the typical case (=best general, one fits all, models), just leave it on default.